# HttpErrorResponse and 403 forbidden

Tags: http-status-code-403

I am creating a portfolio web for a final project with SpringBoot and Angular.

Everything works perfect on localhost but when I do the deploy on Render (back), the data is not shown on the front.

This is what i get on the console [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbUA4.png).

This is what I get on network [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOjTV.png).

This is my main security:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class MainSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsImpl userDetailsServicesImpl;
    
    @Autowired
    JwtEntryPoint jwtEntryPoint;
    
    @Bean
    public JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter(){
        return new JwtTokenFilter();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(jwtEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);           
    }

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
       auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsServicesImpl).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}
```

All the controllers are set up like this:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:4200","https://front-end-jds.web.app"}, maxAge = 3600, allowCredentials="true")
```

I also added this to the main:

```
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200", "https://front-end-jds.web.app"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Content-Type",
                "Accept", "Authorization", "Origin, Accept", "X-Requested-With",
                "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"));
        corsConfiguration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept", "Authorization",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
        corsConfiguration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);
        return new CorsFilter(urlBasedCorsConfigurationSource);
    }
```

I also think that the back is working because I get this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFD7j.png)